# IBInspectable not working in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am using the swift extension.

```
extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
            layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
        }
    }
}
```

Which is cookie cutter from several examples regarding @IBInspectable. However, when I use this in my project, the storyboard does not update while viewing in xcode.

[image]

When compiling and running however, it does show the rounded corners.

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be very very much appreciated. The project is here. github.com/captainchung/test

Answer (score 0):

You also need to set your view as @IBDesignable. You can try to set it over the extension but not sure it would work, it would work if you subclass UIVIew with your own implementation and then use @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable

Comment: Hi Marc, I just tried your suggestion, which is here https://github.com/captainchung/test/blob/master/test/ViewController.swift#L12 but now, in my storyboard, when viewing the designable view in storyboard, it no longer has the background color set in the storyboard.